# Relation between moduli space of flat connections and moduli space of bundles on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I would like to let $X$ be a genus $g$ curve, with $M_{g}(r,d)$ the moduli space of bundles on the curve such that $(r,d)=1$.

Alternatively, we can pick a group $G$, consider principal $G$-bundles $P \to X$ with $\mathcal{A}(P)$ and $\mathcal{A}_{\rm{flat}}(P)$ the infinite dimensional spaces of connections, and flat connections on $P$, respectively.  We let $\mathcal{G}(P)$ be the gauge group consisting of all equivariant maps $u:P \to G$.  The holonomy then produces the well-known isomorphism

$\coprod _{[P]} \mathcal{A}_{\rm{flat}}(P)/\mathcal{G}(P) \simeq \rm{Hom}(\pi_{1}(X), G) / G$.

My first question pertains just to the left-hand side of this expression

(i) So I guess $\mathcal{A}_{\rm{flat}}(P)$ and $\mathcal{G}(P)$ are infinite-dimensional spaces but the quotient turns out to be finite dimensional.  *Then* you take the disjoint union over all equivalence classes of bundles $P \to X$.  How do we know this is well-defined, or finite dimensional after taking the disjoint union?

My second question is how this relates to the moduli space of stable bundles:

(ii) Taking the case where $G=\rm{U}(r)$ or $\rm{SU}(r)$, is it true that

$M_{g}(r,d) \simeq \rm{Hom}(\pi_{1}(X), \rm{U}(r))/\rm{U}(r)?$

or perhaps is something similar true, like if we restrict to bundles of fixed determinant, and let $G=\rm{SU}(r)$?  What I have in mind is the commutator map $G^{2g} \to G$ which allows you to identify $M_{g}(r,d)$ as a subspace of $\rm{U}(r)^{2g}$ modulo $\rm{U}(r)$ acting by conjugation.

Really, I'm just trying to work out a precise correspondence between the moduli space of flat connections and the moduli space of stable bundles on curves.